# Relative path name as Hostname Connection parameter Client using Datasnap and Delphi XE5 when running in Android device

Tags: android, delphi, datasnap

In this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vZItTDbB8cw and many others, one can learn how to configure a Datasnap Client Server System inside Delphi XE5.

This kind of system works very well when the hostname parameter is set using an IP Address  [image]:

The bad news are that the hostname IPAddress can change. That's why I need to set the relative path name of the host server as the HostName.

Consider these:
The hostname is actually resolving to the IP address of the server and the DataSnap server is actually running. I tested this by running the app in windows: I changed the hostname into the relative path name of the server and the connection worked well.

The problem becomes when I try to run the app in the android device: it does not recognize the connection when the hostname is set with the relative path name of the machine. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are referring to relative path of the machine are you talking about network name of the machine?

If the answer is yes then the problem is that your android device is not on the same sub-network than your host machine. This could only work if both your host machine and your mobile phone are on the same VPN.

Anyway the correct solution is to assign your server to some domain and then set that domain name as HostName in your client application.

Comment: Thank you very much. In the beginning I was concerned about setting the server to a fixed IP address as you recommend in your answer, but talking to my partners I found out that there might be no reason for that concern in this case.

Comment: Actually I haven't been suggesting the use of static IP but hte use of a domain. What the use of domain does is that it alows your server to send its IP adress to specific domain server every time it is changed. So when a client tries to conect it first asks the domain server for the IP of your own server.

Comment: In order to use a domain in this case, is it necessary to have a VPN? Would I need to change my protocol to HTTP or can I stay using TCP/IP?

Comment: No you don''t need to use VPN for the usage of domains. A domain name can point to a single computer or to a Gateway of an entire network containing hundred of computers. As I already sad domain allows the client computer to simply request a domain name server (DNS) to get the current IP of your server. Domains don't limit you to usage of any particular protocol so you can freely use TCP/IP, UDP, etc. And by the way HTTP is not standalone network protocol but special protocol, that is build on top of TCP/IP protocols.